# Find the min and max value of second dataframe between 2 dates given by first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have this 2 dummy dataframe

```
np.random.seed(12345)

df1=pd.DataFrame({'name'    :  ['A']*4+['B']*4,
                'start_date':   pd.to_datetime(['2000-03-15', '2000-06-12','2000-09-01', '2001-01-17','2000-03-19', '2000-06-14','2000-09-14', '2001-01-22']),
                'end_date':pd.to_datetime(['2000-06-12','2000-09-01', '2001-01-17','2001-03-19', '2000-06-14','2000-09-14', '2001-01-22','2001-02-01'])})

date=pd.date_range('2000-01-01','2002-01-01')
name=['A']*len(date)+['B']*len(date)
date=date.append(date)
import numpy as np
low=np.random.rand(len(date))
high=low+np.random.rand(len(date))
df2=pd.DataFrame({'name': name, 'date': date, 'low':low,'high':high})
```

for each row in df1, i am given name, start date and end date.

i want to find the maximum in high and the minimum in low that is same as the name and is between the start and end date in df2

Below is my current solution.

```
df1=df1.set_index('name')
df2=df2.set_index(['name','date'])
df2=df2.sort_index()
df1['max']=-1
df1['min']=-1
for name in df1.index.unique():
    df=df2.loc[name]
    tmphigh=[]
    tmplow=[]
    for (_,start_date,end_date,_,_) in df1.loc[name].itertuples(name=None):
        newdf=df.iloc[df.index.searchsorted(start_date): df.index.searchsorted(end_date)]
        tmphigh.append(newdf.high.max())
        tmplow.append(newdf.low.min())
    df1.loc[[name],['max']]=tmphigh
    df1.loc[[name],['min']]=tmplow
```

However, applying over million of row still take quite significant time.
I am wondering if there is an faster way to do it.

[Edit]:
Thanks to Pramote Kuacharoen, i am able to adapt some of his code and achieve 6x speedup over my existing code.

The reason for separating into loops was that i find that including the generating of df2[name] in the apply function would result in significant increase in time spent calculating.

Hence i separate out to calculate it which might have helped reduced the function call to extract all values under name in df2.

I would be glad if somebody can suggest better method than my method. but this is sufficient for me for now.

Below is my current solution

```
from tqdm import tqdm
df1a=df1.groupby('name')
df2a=df2.groupby('name')
mergedf=df1
mergedf['maximum']=-1
mergedf['minimum']=-1
def get_min_max(row):
    dfx=df2x.iloc[df2x.index.searchsorted(row['start_date']): df2x.index.searchsorted(row['end_date'])]
    maximum = dfx['high'].max()
    minimum = dfx['low'].min() 
    return pd.Series({'maximum': maximum, 'minimum': minimum})
for name,df in tqdm(df1a):
    df2x=df2a.get_group(name)
    mergedf.loc[[name],['maximum','minimum']]=df.apply(get_min_max,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'name'    :  ['A']*4+['B']*4,
                'start_date':   pd.to_datetime(['2000-03-15', '2000-06-12','2000-09-01', '2001-01-17','2000-03-19', '2000-06-14','2000-09-14', '2001-01-22']),
                'end_date':pd.to_datetime(['2000-06-12','2000-09-01', '2001-01-17','2001-03-19', '2000-06-14','2000-09-14', '2001-01-22','2001-02-01'])})

date=pd.date_range('2000-01-01','2002-01-01')
name=['A']*len(date)+['B']*len(date)
date=date.append(date)
import numpy as np
low=np.random.rand(len(date))
high=low+np.random.rand(len(date))
df2=pd.DataFrame({'name': name, 'date': date, 'low':low,'high':high})

df2 = df2.set_index('date')

def find_max(row):
    return df2[df2['name'] == row['name']].loc[row['start_date']:row['end_date'], 'high'].max()

def find_min(row):
    return df2[df2['name'] == row['name']].loc[row['start_date']:row['end_date'], 'low'].min()

df1['maximum'] = df1.apply(find_max, axis=1)
df1['minimum'] = df1.apply(find_min, axis=1)
```

Try find min and max in one call. It may save some time.

```
def find_min_max(row):
    dfx = df2[df2['name'] == row['name']].loc[row['start_date']:row['end_date'], ['high', 'low']]
    maximum = dfx['high'].max()
    minimum = dfx['low'].min()
    return pd.Series({'maximum': maximum, 'minimum': minimum})

df1.merge(df1.apply(find_min_max, axis=1), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Try this one: Multiprocessing and Shared Memory. Save it in .py file and run it using command line.  It should be much faster.  I set n_workers to 4. You can change it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed


def find_min_max(name, data_info):

    shm_name, shape, dtype = data_info[0]
    shm1 = SharedMemory(shm_name)
    np1 = np.recarray(shape=shape, dtype=dtype, buf=shm1.buf)

    shm_name, shape, dtype = data_info[1]
    shm2 = SharedMemory(shm_name)
    np2 = np.recarray(shape=shape, dtype=dtype, buf=shm2.buf)

    data1 = np1[np1['name'] == name]
    data2 = np2[np2['name'] == name]

    for rec in data1:
        idx1 = np.searchsorted(data2['date'], rec['start_date'])
        idx2 = np.searchsorted(data2['date'], rec['end_date'])
        data = data2[idx1:idx2]
        np1[rec['index']]['maximum'] = data['high'].max()
        np1[rec['index']]['minimum'] = data['low'].min()


def main():

    np.random.seed(12345)

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':  ['A']*4+['B']*4,
                        'start_date':   pd.to_datetime(['2000-03-15', '2000-06-12', '2000-09-01', '2001-01-17', '2000-03-19', '2000-06-14', '2000-09-14', '2001-01-22']),
                        'end_date': pd.to_datetime(['2000-06-12', '2000-09-01', '2001-01-17', '2001-03-19', '2000-06-14', '2000-09-14', '2001-01-22', '2001-02-01'])})

    date = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2002-01-01')
    name = ['A']*len(date)+['B']*len(date)
    date = date.append(date)
    low = np.random.rand(len(date))
    high = low+np.random.rand(len(date))
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': name, 'date': date, 'low': low, 'high': high})

    df1 = df1.sort_values('name')
    df2 = df2.sort_values(['name', 'date'])
    df1['maximum'] = -1.0
    df1['minimum'] = -1.0

    np1 = df1.to_records(column_dtypes={
        'name': '|S20', 'start_date': '<M8[ns]', 'end_date': '<M8[ns]'})
    np2 = df2.to_records(column_dtypes={
        'name': '|S20', 'date': '<M8[ns]', 'low': '<f8', 'high': '<f8'})

    names = [str.encode(name) for name in df1['name'].unique()]
    del df1
    del df2

    shm1 = SharedMemory(name='d1', create=True, size=np1.nbytes)
    shm2 = SharedMemory(name='d2', create=True, size=np2.nbytes)

    shm1_np_array = np.recarray(
        shape=np1.shape, dtype=np1.dtype, buf=shm1.buf)
    np.copyto(shm1_np_array, np1)
    shm2_np_array = np.recarray(
        shape=np2.shape, dtype=np2.dtype, buf=shm2.buf)
    np.copyto(shm2_np_array, np2)

    data_info = [
        (shm1.name, np1.shape, np1.dtype),
        (shm2.name, np2.shape, np2.dtype)
    ]

    del np1
    del np2

    # Set number of workers
    n_workers = 4

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(n_workers) as exe:
        fs = [exe.submit(find_min_max, name, data_info)
              for name in names]
        for _ in as_completed(fs):
            pass

    print(shm1_np_array)

    shm1.close()
    shm2.close()
    shm1.unlink()
    shm2.unlink()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Sorry, this method seems to be of a slower speed then my naive loop... the loop i created is able to complete within an hour. but i have run the apply method for more than an hour and it is still not completed. not sure if i did something wrong... But i think it is likely due to the apply calling the mask for every row iteration while the loop has extracted that operation out.

Comment: How big is your data?

Comment: df1 has 500k rows and df2 has 37million rows

Comment: Try only df1.apply(find_min_max, axis=1) and see how long it takes to run.

Comment: Other options you may consider: Partition you data, use multiprocessing.

Comment: tried apply method again. but it is still running after more than 2hours.

Comment: I was unable to run multiprocess as it causes memory usage to grow exponentially and crashes my pc

Comment: I changed the code to use multiprocessing and shared memory.  I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since performance is your issue I think [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) can help a lot

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
```

Create dask df

```
ddf1 = dd.from_pandas(df1, npartitions=5) # You can change 5 to higher
```

Funciton for your logic

```
def get_high_low(name, start, end):
    mask = df2['name'].eq(name) & df2['date'].between(start, end)
    low = df2.loc[mask]['low'].min()
    high = df2.loc[mask]['high'].max()
    return {'name': name, 'start_date': start, 'end_date': end, 'max': high, 'min': low}
```

Collect the resulting data into a new dataframe

```
result = ddf1.apply(lambda x: testing(x['name'], x['start_date'], x['end_date']), axis=1, meta=(None, 'object')).compute()
df4 = pd.DataFrame(result.tolist())
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing dask.dask seems to fit my purpose. But for this case, i was unable to get it to work on my dataset with your answer. I had replaced testing to get_high_low in your solution. I added diagnostic but it is not performing any task. 
~~~
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
ProgressBar().register()

Comment: Are you getting an error? My solution works with the example you provided

Comment: No error. it works fine when i reduced the size of df1 from to 1k rows and df2 to 1million rows. but larger will result in similar increase in time taken to load or it just does not progress

Comment: That sounds like a hardware issue, your PC can't process such large files even with multiprocessing